# Could initializing a static char array with a given size using a string literal of a different size cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c, arrays, string, undefined-behavior

In our code base I found something similar to

```
static char foo[4] = "0";
```

Since the string is smaller than the array, is this still well-defined?
Hypothetically, what if I had

```
static char bar[4] = "01234";
```

I assume the array would be initialized to "0123". But is this guaranteed by the standard or also another possible case of undefined behavior?

Comment: There is no partial initialization in C. When you assign value with the declaration, the whole object is initialized (be it array or struct). Any element for which you have not specified value is initialized with 0 (if number) or with NULL (if pointer). char is a numeric type so the rest of the elements will be set to 0 (which is the '\0' character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the string is smaller than the array, is this still well-defined?

Yes,

```
static char foo[4] = "0";
```

is well defined. `foo` will contain `'0'`, `'\0'`, `'\0'` and `'\0'`.

The snippet

```
static char bar[4] = "01234";
```

is constraint violation. While

```
static char bar[4] = "0123";
```

is well defined until `bar` is not accessed as a *string*. In this case `bar` is a `char` array with 4 characters `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'` and `'3'`. You may get a warning for the latter case that

```
Initializer-string for char array is too long
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what the 'foo' array contains? I assume it would be ['0'][NULL][garbage][garbage]? Or perhaps ['0'][NULL][NULL][NULL]?

Comment: @DeathTails; Updated the answer. BTW, `NULL` is a macro used for null pointer, not for null string.

Comment: No, in the second case you absolutely will get a diagnostic message, since the code is invalid. There's no "may" here.

Comment: @AnT Oops! Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

From [section 6.7.8.21 of the C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

Objects with static storage duration are initialized with the value 0.  So initializing a fixed size character array with a string constant shorter than the array results in the remaining bytes containing the value 0.

Also, from 6.7.8.32:

> The declaration
>
> ```
> char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines "plain" char array objects s and t whose elements are initialized with character string
>   literals. This declaration is identical to
>
> ```
> char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
> t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
> ```

Note that extra characters in a string constant (including the NULL terminator) are discarded when initializing the array.

So in the case of `bar` in  your example, it would contain the characters `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`.

So to summarize, both situations are well-defined.

Comment: Surprisingly, another incorrect answer with the same error.  C language can discard the implicit terminating `'\0'` character when the initializing literal is too long. But C **never** discards any explicitly specified characters of the literal. The initialization of `bar` is a constraint violation. It is invalid. This is what the example in the standard is intended to illustrate. `char t[3] = "abc";` is valid C, but `char t[3] = "abcd"` would not be. The latter is a compile error. Same as `bar` in the OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

The first variant

```
static char foo[4] = "0";
```

is well-defined. The whole array is initialized. `foo[0]` is set to `'0'` while the rest of the array is filled with integral zero values (i.e. `'\0'`) all the way to the end.

The second variant

```
static char bar[4] = "01234";
```

is a constraint violation, i.e. an error, invalid code. In C when you are initializing a char array with string literal, you are allowed to drop off the implicit terminating `'\0'` character, but not any of the explicitly specified characters in the initializer. You can't initialize a `char` array of length 4 with a string literal of length 5.

E.g. this would still be valid

```
static char bar[4] = "0123";
```

but not what you have.

Remember

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
>   **2** No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.
>   ...
>   **14** An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.